# Need to use nest with custom webclient to support connection authenticated with X509Certificate

Tags: elasticsearch, webclient, x509certificate, nest

I have a derived class of WebClient that overrides WebRequest to return a request object with the certificate needed to talk to our ElasticSearch cluster via proxy.  How do I use this with Nest? Thanks.

Comment: Posted on github. Sorry about the cross post. Please reply there instead.
https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/issues/454

Comment: I've also answered the question on SO, can you accept it please? I like to keep my answered ration for the tag nest up on SO :)

Comment: wow I just saw your comment from last year. The answer did work, thanks! Answer accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subclass `Connection`

https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/blob/master/src/Nest/Domain/Connection/Connection.cs

And override

```
protected override HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string path, string method)
{
       //return your derived WebRequest here.
}
```

then use this overload on ElasticClient

https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/blob/master/src/Nest/ElasticClient.cs#L29

To use your custom `IConnection`.